# Taking picture using OpenCV without led light on python

Tags: python, windows, opencv, camera

I was able to capture an image using `openCV`.

What I couldn't figure out is how to capture a picture without the little `LED` light on. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is my function:

```
def cheese():
    vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if vc.isOpened():  # try to get the first frame
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    img = Image.fromarray(frame)
    return img
else:
    rval = False
```

Answer (score 0):

The properties of videocapture have get / set methods as  id/value pair and the led mode is the id 412. And led selector 411 !  Technically you should do :
vc.set(412,your_value ) but that one (412) is a constant.

Comment: ,I can't change constant, so what do i have to do to take the picture?